# PostgreSQL - reindex when add new index

Tags: postgresql, indexing, reindex

I have a table with 100k records without indexes. I created a new index on column that is used for left join.
Do I need to reindex my table?

Creation of an index took a few ms. So I am guessing that query can not use this index (no data) until I reindex my table (in case I would have other indexes I would reindex only index - I read the manual).

I can't find any information when new index is populated with data? Is this done automatically? When?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once `CREATE INDEX` has finished, the index is ready to be used. There is no need to run `REINDEX` after that.

From the `REINDEX` [documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/sql-reindex.html):

> REINDEX is similar to a drop and recreate of the index in that the index contents are rebuilt from scratch. However, the locking considerations are rather different. REINDEX locks out writes but not reads of the index's parent table.

That means `REINDEX` behaves similar to `CREATE` after `DROP`.

And from the `CREATE INDEX` [documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createindex.html):

> Creating an index can interfere with regular operation of a database. Normally PostgreSQL locks the table to be indexed against writes and performs the entire index build with a single scan of the table. Other transactions can still read the table, but if they try to insert, update, or delete rows in the table they will block until the index build is finished.

I think this unambiguously explains that creation implies indexation.

Whether or not a specific query *uses* the index depends on many different things though. If your query doesn't use the index, you need to post the query, the table definitions (e.g. as a `create table` statement), the index you have defined and the output of `explain (analyze, verbose)` of your query.

Comment: This doesn't sound logic to me, that's why I ask the question. The database must iterate through data at some point and position records in appropriate order. This can not be done in an instinct (I think)?

Comment: @Makla: A few milliseconds sounds reasonable to build an index on such a small table using decent hardware. Believe me: the index **is** completely built and ready when the `create index` statement has finished.